# Data Lost on Page Refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I'm trying to show an item in a product component, and everything works fine using `react-router-dom` (Routes), but when I reload the page I lose the data and the items are gone. I know that is because of the match object from `react-router-dom`

The way I'm doing all is passing the `id` of the item as argument to my `getById` action, the problem is that the `id` that I'm passing is from the `match.params` object

**Product Component**

```
class Producto extends Component {


    static propTypes = {
        getById: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getById(this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    render() {
        const [item] = this.props.item.items;
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm="12" md="8">
                        <h3>{item.nombre}</h3>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm="12" md="4">
                        <h3>{item.precio}</h3>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    item: state.item
})

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {getById}
)(Producto);
```

**Recents component**

This component shows the recent products

```
items.map( item => (
    <Col>
        <Card>

            <CardImg top width="100%" src= {`../../../${item.imagenes[0].path}`}></CardImg>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>
                        <NavLink><Link to={`/producto/${item._id}`}>{item.nombre}</Link></NavLink>
                    </CardTitle>
                    <CardText>{item.descripcion}</CardText>
                    <Button>Comprar</Button>
                 </CardBody>
         </Card>
     </Col>
 ))
```

**Finally my getById action**

```
export const getById = id => dispatch => {
    axios
        .get(`/api/items/${id}`)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ITEMS_BY_ID,
                payload: res.data
            })
        });
}
```

If you want more context about this is my git repository:

https://github.com/Franguestclain/OnlineStore